# Server memory overload when upload multiple files

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

sorry for english , in my project the user can upload from 1 to 14 file (file from 2mb to 50mb)with ajax ,this is the simple php code :

```
//percorso della cartella dove mettere i file caricati dagli utenti
$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploaded/';



############################################
#              FILE 1                      #
############################################

//solo per il file 1
if(!isset( $_FILES['stl1']['tmp_name']) OR $_FILES['stl1']   ['tmp_name']==''){
   $user->set_errors('File 1 non selezionato!!!');

}

//se presente il file 1
if(isset( $_FILES['stl1']['tmp_name']) AND $_FILES['stl1']['tmp_name']!=''){
   //se non c'è l'id del materiale
   if(!isset($_POST['materiale1'])){
      $user->set_errors('Manca il materiale!!!');

   }

   else{

      //Recupero il percorso temporaneo del file
      $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['stl1']['tmp_name'];

      //recupero il nome originale del file caricato
      $userfile_name = $_FILES['stl1']['name'];



  //copio il file dalla sua posizione temporanea alla mia cartella upload
  if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir . $nome_dropbox)) {
    //Se l'operazione è andata a buon fine...
       //inserisco nel db il file 
                    if($user->insert_lavorazioni($_POST['materiale1'],
                                 $_POST['numero_scheda'],
                                 $_POST['colore'],
                                 $userfile_name)){

                                 $user->debug[]='<br>Lavorazione inserita nel db';



                    }else{
                          $user->set_errors('Problemi nell\'inserimento lavorazione nel db');

                    }


  }else{
    //Se l'operazione è fallta...
    $user->set_errors('Upload NON valido!'); 
  }







   }

}
```

For every file i called another script equal to this .When more user upload file simultaneously the server memory go to overload and other ajax request for example populate dinamically select input dont work .

How can i reduce memory usage ?

Comment: How many simultaneous users are you talking about? What is the output of `ini_get('memory_limit');`? You also didn't mention which web server you are using.

Comment: The memory is :768M.if 2 user send 14 file simultaneously the usage  amount of memory is near 90% if 3   user send file ther'is an overload and other ajax request dont work . My hosting have this features :Cores: 2 x 2.1 ghz - Physical Memory: 1 Gbyte - Virtual Memory: 8 Gbyte - HD: SSD.12 Core Server Minimum - 64 GB RAM Server Minimum

Comment: 14*2*50 = 1400 MB. You're only giving it 768. What is the actual error message you get?

Comment: The server go until 100% , the other ajax request don't work  . The project is made for upload file to server and after on dropbox (with cronjob) . how can i allows user to upload file with normal memory usage ? there is another way than move_file_upload ?

Comment: *The server go until 100% , the other ajax request don't work* - That doesn't actually answer my question. The server's *what* goes to 100%? CPU? Memory usage? What are you using to determine that? What does "don't work" mean? What happens? Any error messages? Be specific.

Comment: Memory usage is near to 100% is almost impossible for other user to use the website , the ajax request return the alert called on ajax request error: error: function()
                  {
                    alert("Chiamata fallita fformdata, si prega di riprovare...");
                  },